Ubuntu 24.04 hfsplus causes corrupted disk
I have installed on my scandisk a partion with hfsplus without journalising. I did this using MacOS Big sur.
I installed the hfsprogs and hfsplus, and used rsync to copy my entire home directory of 20 GB, after a while of basically reading (coping from that disk) almost no more write.
The disk was mounted read only. Diskutility of the Mac using first aid cannot fix the error, nor Ubuntu's testdisk, and neither fsck.hfsplus
In fact
fsck.hfsplus -l -n /dev/sdd2
leads to
Checking catalog file.
   Illegal name
   Illegal name
   Illegal name
   Illegal name
   Invalid map node linkage
(4, 63488)

And
fsck.hfsplus -fryd /dev/sdb3
leads so segmentation fault
Is this a known issue?
Should hfsplus be avoided (but my idea was to use it for backups of the Mac and the Linux system)?
any ideas?
Thanks
Uwe Brauer

ah, sorry, I meant of course Ubuntu 24! (I mentioned 16 and 18 since I had the problem there as well).
So the hsfplus problem and the corrupt disk is a problem of Ubuntu 24, sorry for the typo

How can I change the title, because the difference between 14 and 24 is important!

ah, it is in all cases, 24.04 LTS, 18.04 LTS and 16.04 LTS

Please remove any mention to the EOL versions 16.04 and 18.04 they are off topic.

I also have a SanDisk Extreme Pro 4TB hfs+ which became read-only after using it for backup with a Synology NAS. fsck.hfsplus leads also to segfault. I'm still investigating the problem

I run more and more experiments and I always end up with a corrupted partion that has hfs+ journaling disabled. I even tried hfsplus journaling enabled, which is usually mounted read only in Ubuntu. After running sudo mount -t hfsplus -o remount,force,rw /media/oub/XXX/ I could write to the disk but rsync finished badly with a core dump. So I presume for the moment the best solution is to divide the external disk: one partition with hfs+ journaling enabled to which the Mac can write and Linux read and one with say ext4 to which Linux can write and Mac should read

The instructions of who to compile the ext4 driver can be found in
(this can be found in https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2024/mounting-ext4-linux-usb-drive-on-macos-2024 but so far I could not compile it

I somehow found a workaround. Since I had more and more problems with HFS+ (journaling disabled) including segfaults. So I generated 2 partions on the external disk,

hfs+ journaling enabled, for writing with MacOS and reading with Linux
ext4, for writing with Linux.

I am on Big Sur, and installed MacFuse quite some time ago. I then installed successfully fuse-ext2 using the script provided. It says ext2 but it supports ext2, ext3 and ext4 you can even achieve write access which at the moment I prefer not to have. I am not entirely sure how it works on more recent MacOS, but you might give a try.
